# Simplest way to overlay a text + rectangle label an image?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, overlays

For my figures thus far I've been using LaTeX's straightforward figure code, i.e.:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6.5in]{figure.png}
    \caption[Stuff here]{(A) More stuff here and (B) here.}
    \label{background-operating-mode}
\end{figure}
```

All well and good until I've got a multi-part figure, e.g., part (A) and part (B) that need to be labeled within the same PNG file. What I'd like to do is this: insert the PNG file as the 'bottom layer'; on top of that, in a location of my choosing, put in a black rectangle, as the 'middle layer'; on top of that, in roughly the same location, put in a white character of text saying, for example, "A".

I've searched and saw that TikZ may be a way to do this. However I'm deeply confused by it (first attempt below), so I ask, is there a simpler way to achieve this very basic task? I'm not looking to draw a figure from scratch... just want to overlay a rectangle and a character on a PNG. What's the simplest way to do this?

```
\noindent \begin{tikzpicture}
    {\includegraphics[width=6.5in]{group-figures/background/fig1.png}};
    \fill (0,0) rectangle (20pt, 20pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: See also [Drawing on an image with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the `onimage` package from the `From Answers to Packages` project, which implements the answer given in [Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz).

To use the package: Download the file `onimage.dtx` from [bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/files](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/files), run `pdflatex` on it, and move the resulting `.sty` file to your working directory.

Then you can load the `onimage` package and use the `tikzonimage` environment, which has the form

```
\begin{tikzonimage}[<options for includegraphics>]{<image name>}[<options for TikZ>]
...
\end{tikzonimage}`
```

The coordinate system will be scaled in such a way that `(0,0)` is the bottom left corner of the image, and `(1,1)` is the top right. You can disable this scaling, if you wish, by setting the key `tsx/scale cs=none` in the optional TikZ arguments.

Here's a simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{onimage}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzonimage}{bottle.jpg}
    \draw [orange, line width=5pt] (0.5,0.92) circle [radius=0.75cm];
\end{tikzonimage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can switch on a grid to help you position your TikZ objects by setting the key `tsx/show help lines`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{onimage}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzonimage}{bottle.jpg}[tsx/show help lines]
    \draw [orange, line width=5pt] (0.5,0.92) circle [radius=0.75cm];
\end{tikzonimage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In order to get the labels to look like you described them, you can use the `font=<font commands>` option to set the font options, `fill=<color>` for the background and `text=<color>` for the text color. To keep things neat, you can define a new style for this using

```
\tikzset{
     <new style name>/.style={
        fill=black,
        text=white,
        font=\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\Large\bfseries
    }
}
```

Here's an example in which I've also added the label position (0.2 cm from the bottom right edge of the images) as part of the style definition, and made the style alter the `every node/.style`, which is applied to all nodes in a TikZ picture. This allows us to apply this newly defined style to the whole TikZ picture in the `tikzonimage` optional argument, instead of applying it to the node itself using `\node [<style>] {};`:

[image]

```
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    image label/.style={
        every node/.style={
            fill=black,
            text=white,
            font=\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\Large\bfseries,
            anchor=south east,
            xshift=-0.2cm,
            yshift=0.2cm,
            at={(1,0)}
        }
    }
}

\begin{tikzonimage}[width=0.5\textwidth]{bottle}[image label]
\node{A};
\end{tikzonimage}
\begin{tikzonimage}[width=0.25\textwidth]{bottle}[image label]
\node{B};
\end{tikzonimage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And a follow-up question, how do I change the color, font type and size in the following command: \node at (0.015,0.98) {A}; I can change color with \node at (0.015,0.98) {{\color{white}A}}; is this the best way?

Comment: Hmmm, I've figured that I can do this, but it seems hilariously ugly: \node at (0.015,0.98) {{\color{white}\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont{\LARGE{\bfseries{A}}}}};

Comment: I've added an example that shows how to use the `fill`, `text`, and `font` keys.

Comment: @Jake: Have you ever used this in combination with [TikzEdt](http://www.tikzedt.org/)? I couldn't get it to work. It kept complaining that it couldn't find the `onimage.sty`, even though it was fine in the Miktex installation.

Comment: It would be cool if the onimage package makes it to ctan at some point.