# Tikz overlays on subfigures in memoir

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, memoir

Say I have the following code in a document typeset with `memoir`:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subbottom[]{
\label{sub1}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{test.png}}%
\subbottom[]{
\label{sub2}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{test.png}}%
\caption{\subcaptionref{sub1}: Left of the figure. \subcaptionref{sub2}: Right of the figure}
\end{figure}
```

which generates the following figure:

[image]

I would like to be able to overlay some text and mathematical formula on each of the images (with coordinates relative to each image).

I read these two posts:

- [Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz)
- [Simplest way to overlay a text + rectangle label an image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30427/simplest-way-to-overlay-a-text-rectangle-label-a-png-figure)

I really like the solution described in the first of them, i.e. using `tikz` commands to overlay text and formulae.

However, the examples they provide require using a `tikzpicture` environment, which seems to prevent me from using `\subbottom[]` for subfigures in memoir.

How can I use `tikzpicture and` scope in combination with `subbottom` in `memoir`?

For the sake of the example, say I want to overlay the symbol `$\phi$` on the center of the subfigure of the left, and the symbol `$\psi$` on the center of the subfigure on the right (both inside small white boxes).

Comment: what is the problem with `\subbottom` and `tikzpicture`? I use it daily. How do you use it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you asked for a tikz way, here is one. Of course you can tidy up the code a lot and create commands and such, but the example below shows you a possible way

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subbottom[]{%
\label{sub1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt,remember picture]
\node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{test.jpg}};
\node[fill=green!20] (a) at (1,1) {A node};
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\subbottom[]{
\label{sub2}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt,remember picture]
\node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{test.jpg}};
\node[fill=red!20] (b) at (0.5,0.5) {A node};
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
 \draw[->,red,very thick] (a) to[bend right] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{\subcaptionref{sub1}: Left of the figure. \subcaptionref{sub2}: Right
of the figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

basically you but the picture in a node and the you can but other nodes on top. by telling tikz to remember the nodes you can later connect those nodes

[image]

Comment: This is great. Thanks!! When you say \node[fill=red!20], what is the number `20` for? Also, do you know how can I change the width and height of the box of the node? (without changing the text or the size of the text)

Comment: @roseck: `<colour>!<num>` uses the notation of [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor). It means `<num>`% of colour `<colour>`. In this case, a fill of 20% red... which is pinkish, like uncooked sausage. `green!20` is more like *very* old sausage.

Comment: @roseck you can increase the box of `A node` by saying `\node[fill=green!20,inner sep=10pt]`. I initially set the inner sep to 0 because I wanted to avoid extra space around the picture. You could also specify `minimum width=20pt`and `minimum height=40pt`.

Answer (score 7):

You don't really need TikZ for this. However, it does allow for more freedom and variability in terms of overlaying graphics. As-is, overlays are possible via `\ooalign`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\newsubfloat{figure}% Allows \subbottom and \subtop in figure
\newsavebox{\myfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \savebox{\myfig}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{tiger}}% Store image
  \subbottom[]{%
    \label{sub1}%
    \ooalign{\usebox{\myfig}\cr\hss\raisebox{\dimexpr.5\ht\myfig-.5\baselineskip}{\colorbox{white}{\Huge$\phi$}}\hss}}%
  \subbottom[]{%
    \label{sub2}%
    \usebox{\myfig}}%
  \caption{\subcaptionref{sub1}:~Left of the figure. \subcaptionref{sub2}:~Right of the figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The images are set in a box (`\myfig`) in order to obtain the appropriate height (via `\ht\myfig`). `\ooalign` overlays the dual content (image and formula) while `\raisebox` moves the formula into position vertically.

See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/5764) for a quick course in `\ooalign`.