# Normalized coordinates for image overlays in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simplest way to overlay a text + rectangle label an image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30427/simplest-way-to-overlay-a-text-rectangle-label-an-image)
>   [Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/2975)

I read the following in the TikZ manual:

> There are different ways of specifying coordinates. The easiest way is
>   to say something like (10pt,2cm). This means 10pt in x-direction and
>   2cm in y-directions.  Alternatively, **you can also leave out the units**
>   as in (1,2), which means “one times the current x-vector plus twice
>   the current y-vector.” These vectors **default to 1cm** in the x-direction
>   and 1cm in the y-direction, respectively.

Say I have an image and that I want to overlay stuff on it. Is there a way to set up coordinates that are **normalized** to the size of the figure?

For example say I want to place a picture `image.png` within a `tikzpicture`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt,remember picture]
\node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{image.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

I would like to use **normalized** coordinates when drawing `nodes` on top of it, such that I have the following reference frame:

```
   0                   1
   . -------------------> X 
   |                   | 
   |                   | 
   |       Figure      | 
   |                   | 
   |                   | 
 1 | -------------------
   V
   Y
```

In other words I would like to have  `(1,1)` refer to the bottom right corner, and `(0,0)` refer to the upper left corner of the figure (or image).

Comment: This should be answered by [Drawing on an image with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/2975). You might need to add a `-` for the `y` value to get this axis downwards. We were planning to produce a package for this, btw.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Well, the package is basically ready, it's just not on CTAN. There's an explanation how to use it at [Simplest way to overlay a text + rectangle label a PNG figure?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30427/2552)

Comment: @MartinScharrer, I am confused. I read both threads carefully before posting and I started the question because I could not get normalized coordinates when drawing. That's also why I quoted the paragraph from the TikZ manual, because according to the manual coordinates are measured by default in `cm`, not as normalized coordinates with respect to the content of the `tikzpicture` environment.

Comment: @roseck: Yes, by default they are. But both these solutions redefine the unit vectors so they are normalised according to the image dimensions. That's what the keys `x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}` do in [Drawing on an image with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/2975).

Comment: @roseck: Coordinates like `(<unitless number>,<unitless number>)` always referenced to the unit vectors. These simply happen to have an default value of `1cm`, which can be easily changed, even locally.

Comment: @roseck: If you want the y unit vector to point down, just replace `anchor=south west` with `anchor=north west`, and `x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}` with `x={(image.north east)},y={(image.south west)}`.

Comment: Thanks to both, and thanks especially to @Jake! I was missing that bit.