# Tikz picture label on bottom right

Tags: tikz-pgf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simplest way to overlay a text + rectangle label an image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30427/simplest-way-to-overlay-a-text-rectangle-label-an-image)

I have to insert manny pictures in document, and all should have bottom right caption but on the top of the picture (inside the picture). This caption should have a 3px bottom and right margin and possible white background color - like white box with text inside. Text should be only one line, but I dont know in advance how long it will be - possibly not more than 5-7 characters.

How can i do that with TIKZ package?

Comment: Take a look at the solution at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30435/2552, you might be able to adapt that solution.

Comment: Nice one, I am still twiddling a bit but 'we have the solution'.

10x