# putting a box over an image in beamer presentation

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics

In a Beamer presentation, I want to put a box over a graphic file. For example, in one slide, I want to put a graphic file:
[image: first slide]

And, in the next slide, I want to put a box on the image:
[image: second slide]

This style of work was what I usually do with MS Powerpoint. I was wondering how I can do this with Beamer. If there is any other elegant way to do this with the similar purpose (i.e. pointing and emphasizing a part of images), I am open to any suggestion as well.

Comment: I don't think this is an exact duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30427/simplest-way-to-overlay-a-text-rectangle-label-an-image, since it's not only concerned with putting a rectangle over an image, but to make the rectangle appear from one frame to the next.

Comment: @Jake I agree. This is a slightly different question as you indicated. However, I was able to implement the one-frame-to-the-next effect by putting `\pause` in the `tikzonimage` environment.

Comment: Ah, that's great! I still think it would be nice to reopen this question and have you self-answer it, because this is a common problem, and I, for one, wouldn't immediately know how to go about it.

Answer (score 4):

How about this: you have three commands:

- `\imagenode` for inserting the picture and setting up some dimensions
- the optional `\imagegrid` which helps putting the frame
- `\highlightbox` for drawing the frame

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\imagenode}[2][1]% [scale], filename
{   \node[above right,inner sep=0] (myimage) {\includegraphics[scale=#1]{#2}};
    \path (myimage.north east);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\myimagex}{\myimagey}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myimagewidth}{\myimagex/28.453}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myimageheight}{\myimagey/28.453}
}

\newcommand{\imagegrid}[4][help lines]% [options], steps, font, precision
{   \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=#4}
    \foreach \x in {0,...,#2}
    {   \draw[#1] (\x/#2*\myimagewidth,\myimageheight) -- (\x/#2*\myimagewidth,0) node[below] {#3\pgfmathparse{\x/#2}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}};
        \draw[#1] (\myimagewidth,\x/#2*\myimageheight) -- (0,\x/#2*\myimageheight) node[left] {#3\pgfmathparse{\x/#2}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}};
    }
}

\newcommand{\highlightbox}[8][densely dashed,thick]% [options], left, low, right, up, node options, node text, overlay spec
{   \only<#8>{\draw[#1] (#2*\myimagewidth, #3*\myimageheight) rectangle node[#6] {#7} (#4*\myimagewidth, #5*\myimageheight);}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \imagenode[3]{book.png}

        \imagegrid{10}{\tiny}{1}

        \highlightbox[red,very thick]{0.1}{0.1}{0.7}{0.2}{blue}{red frame}{2}
        \highlightbox{0}{0.3}{0.3}{0.7}{circle,draw,fill=green!50!gray,solid}{dash}{2-3}
        \highlightbox[blue,fill=blue,fill opacity=0.3]{0.42}{0.23}{0.65}{0.74}{opacity=0.8,fill=orange,text opacity=1}{!?}{1,3}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]