# Map with explaining pictures

Tags: beamer, node-connections, overpic

I try to achive something like this:
[image: Map with explaining pictures]

It is a photo I made in the local zoo. Sorry for the poor quality.

I like the idea of a map containing explaining images and try to do the same with beamer. Unfortunately my output is very poor. My first attempt has the following code:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass[a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[] (image) at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{map.jpg}};
  \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
    \node[] (descriptionimage) at (1.1, 0.25) {\framebox{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{bird.jpg}}};
    \node[] (markhere) at (0.7, 0.25) {};
    \draw [thin, red, fill=red] (markhere) circle (4pt);
    \path[->,red] (descriptionimage) edge [out=90, in=0] (markhere);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Since I don't use tikz very often I have no idea of how to draw elegant lines between the markhere node (maybe dotted lines) and how to get the small description text below the explaining image.

Could anyone help me to find a more elegant solution and maybe find a more elegant code?

Comment: You code looks pretty OK. Can you elaborate on the kind of elegance you are looking for?

Comment: The arrow looks quite ungracefull. I'd like to have more modern looking lines (dotted lines horizontal and vertical lines). Is there a way to say "mark here on the map, place the picture here and 'autoroute' a nice looking connection between the mark and the pic"? I'm also looking for a way to set a little text under the explaining pics (see picture above).

Comment: Do you have those beautiful cut-out animal pictures? Can you sample one here such that we can use it in the solution? I guess any world map will do.

Comment: To be honest, I only want to adapt the idea. What I really want to do is to show a technical drawing, mark a point and show a detail (a photo) in the explaining picture. The photos I will use will be cut-out. In my next two comments I will post links to a map and another picture (because of the long link text)

Comment: A Worldmap: http://www.google.de/imgres?q=worldmap&um=1&hl=de&sa=N&tbo=d&biw=1020&bih=511&tbm=isch&tbnid=q-xBxllchog0_M:&imgrefurl=http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:World_map_blank_gmt.png&docid=RObLOFdCF6vONM&imgurl=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f3/World_map_blank_gmt.png&w=5700&h=2940&ei=od2sUJnwLoaltAa41YDYBA&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=4&vpy=252&dur=2954&hovh=161&hovw=313&tx=111&ty=153&sig=105658228558465320267&page=1&tbnh=108&tbnw=160&start=0&ndsp=8&ved=1t:429,r:4,s:0,i:97

Comment: A Bird: http://www.google.de/imgres?q=bird&hl=de&tbo=d&biw=1020&bih=511&tbm=isch&tbnid=dE7-rNQGRH8bmM:&imgrefurl=http://chr.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Bird.parts.jpg&docid=wkpsncAvpbHKSM&imgurl=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/Bird.parts.jpg&w=449&h=325&ei=QN6sUKHoAsXHtAbpkYHwDA&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=363&vpy=161&dur=2748&hovh=191&hovw=264&tx=137&ty=116&sig=105658228558465320267&page=3&tbnh=141&tbnw=204&start=26&ndsp=20&ved=1t:429,r:38,s:0,i:278

Comment: Out of curiousity: why would you do this in LaTeX and not in GIMP or Inkscape and then export it as a graphic that can be used in your LaTeX document.

Comment: Sometimes I have to work on a Windows computer and I'm not allowed to install anything. But fortunately there is a full texlive install.

Answer (score 7):

For a paper I once wrote I used the `spy` library of `tikz` to zoom into a photo. Maybe you can whip up something with the code below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
    \PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\newcommand{\imsize}{\linewidth}
\newlength\imagewidth
\newlength\imagescale

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetlength{\imagewidth}{\imsize}
\pgfmathsetlength{\imagescale}{\imagewidth/5700}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \def\magnification{3}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=\imagescale,
        y=-\imagescale,
        spy using outlines={rectangle, magnification=\magnification,size=100}]
        \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{World_map_blank_gmt}};
        \spy [red,connect spies] on (1490,988) in node at (0,2000);
        \node at (0,3000) {Florida};
        \spy [red,connect spies] on (3392,1812) in node at (5700,500);
        \node at (5700,1500) {Madagascar};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is nice, but in this case I don't need a zoomed section of the big picture. I want to "fill the spy glass" with a different pictures. However I will copy your code. I'm shure I will need it someday.

Answer (score 7):

You could relatively easily knit your own functions to accomplish this with varying degrees of automation. Here's a starting point building on [Simplest way to overlay a text + rectangle label an image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30427/simplest-way-to-overlay-a-text-rectangle-label-an-image):

```
\begin{tikzonimage}{bottle.jpg}
    \nicelabel{0.5,0.92}{Lid}
    \nicelabel[nice label position=below right]{0.7,0.56}{Pearls}
    \nicelabel[nice label position=above left]{0.3,0.1}{Corner}
\end{tikzonimage}
```

[image]

---

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{onimage}

\tikzset{nice label position/.is choice,
    nice label position/above right/.code={
        \def\xpos{1.2}
        \def\startangle{45}
        \tikzset{nice label/.style={anchor=west, yshift=4ex}}
    },
    nice label position/below right/.code={
        \def\xpos{1.2}
        \def\startangle{-45}
        \tikzset{nice label/.style={anchor=west, yshift=-4ex}}
    },
    nice label position/above left/.code={
        \def\xpos{-0.2}
        \def\startangle{135}
        \tikzset{nice label/.style={anchor=east, yshift=4ex}}
    },
    nice label position/below left/.code={
        \def\xpos{-0.2}
        \def\startangle{225}
        \tikzset{nice label/.style={anchor=east, yshift=-4ex}}
    }
}

\newcommand{\nicelabel}[3][]{
    \tikzset{nice label position=above right,#1}
    \node (highlight) at (#2) [circle, draw, orange, ultra thick, minimum width=0.75cm] {};
    \node (label) at (#2-|{\xpos,0}) [nice label] {#3};
    \draw [orange, thick] (highlight) -- ++(\startangle:1.414*4ex) -- (label);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzonimage}{bottle.jpg}
    \nicelabel{0.5,0.92}{Lid}
    \nicelabel[nice label position=below right]{0.7,0.56}{Pearls}
    \nicelabel[nice label position=above left]{0.3,0.1}{Corner}
\end{tikzonimage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example has a siginficant lack of birds ;)

Answer (score 3):

I used a suggestion from the comments and used inkscape + latex export to render the text. This is strictly speaking not an answer to your question but might solve the underlying problem. Took two minutes to create.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\input{murica.pdf_tex}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got some nice answers now but I tried to solve it by myself. This is the code:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass[a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  %Hauptbild einfügen
  \node (image) at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{map}};
  \begin{scope}
    %Markierungskoordinaten
    \node[xshift=-.11cm, yshift=1.3cm] (markhere) at (image.center) {};
    %Markierung zeichnen (Kreis)
    \draw [very thick, red, minimum width=.5cm] (markhere) circle (4pt);
    %Nebenbild einfügen
    \node [xshift=4.5cm, yshift=-.5cm, inner sep=o](descriptionimage) at (image.center) {\framebox{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{gimpel}}};
    %Pfad zeichnen
    \coordinate [left=2cm of descriptionimage](between node);
    \draw[red, very thick, dotted] (markhere.east) -| (between node) -+ (descriptionimage.west);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives me the following result:

[image]

As you can see, there is a gap in the between node and left of the descriptionimage. I'm wondering why are these gaps there and how could I let them disappear?

Edit:
Problem solved after reading Jake's comment.

Comment: Don't use `\node` when all you need is a `\coordinate` (or a `\node` with the `coordinate` key). Nodes by default introduce white space due to the `inner sep`, whereas `coordinate`s don't.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This and your hint about inner sep helped to solve the problem.