# Creating overlapping text and image

Tags: graphics

I am trying to make a title page for my master's thesis, and I want my name (written in text) and signature (with transparent background) slightly overlapping.

My thought was to adjust the distance between the picture and the text, but I don't know how.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{Illustrations/signature-01.eps}
% adjust distance here to make the picture and the text overlap
\centerline{\large\normalfont\bfseries NAME}
\end{figure}
```

I have tried with captions as well, but I could not get rid of the caption label with the `\caption*` command. It seemed like it does not work when I am using `memoir` class and the `sidecap` package.

#### Working example

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{memoir}

% Packages (most of them)
\usepackage[english, danish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{gensymb}    

% Titlepage
\newlength{\drop}%
\newcommand*{\titleMS}{\begingroup% MS Thesis
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newgeometry{left=25mm,right=25mm}
\drop=0.1\textheight
\vspace*{0.5\drop}
\centering
{\huge\sffamily\bfseries
UNIVERSITY \\
\Large\sffamily\mdseries Department}\\[2\baselineskip]
{\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries TITLE}\par

\vfill

{\Large Master's Thesis\\ 30 \textsc{ects} points}\par

\vfill

{\large \textbf{Author}\\
NAME\\
EDUCATION\\
\textbf{Supervisors}\\
NAME AND TITLE\\
\textbf{Submitted}\\
DATE}\par

\vspace{\drop}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{Illustrations/signature-01.eps}
% adjust distance here to make the picture and the text overlap
\centerline{\large\normalfont\bfseries NAME}
\end{figure}

\vspace*{\drop}
\endgroup
\pagebreak
\restoregeometry}


\begin{document}
\fontfamily{pplj}\selectfont
\selectlanguage{english}
\titleMS
my\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't get rid of the caption, get rid of the whole figure environment. It is only disturbing here.

Comment: `\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{example-image.pdf}
\par
 \vspace{-1cm}
 \centerline{\large\normalfont\bfseries NAME}` replace the figure by yours. Make sure there is a `\par`.

Comment: Here is a good example: [Simplest way to overlay a text + rectangle label an image?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30427/5764)

Comment: Also the `\stackinset` macro of the `stackengine` package can do this.

Comment: Alternately, From the left or right use \rlap or \llap. From the bottom or top use \raisebox{some distance}[0pt][0pt]{text}

Comment: @Johannes_B Do you want to answer?

Answer (score 3):

We can use the command for spacing out parts here as well, but we give it a negative space. I tried to clean the code a bit.

As you want to have extra margins for the titlepage, you can completely drop memoir here, do your titlepage and include it in the thesis. There is really no use for toubling with margins.

[image: christofferTitlepage]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\geometry{margin=25mm}

\newlength{\drop}%
\newcommand*{\titleMS}{
    \begin{titlepage}
\fontfamily{pplj}\selectfont
    \drop=0.1\textheight
    \vspace*{0.5\drop}
    \centering
    {\huge\sffamily\bfseries
        UNIVERSITY \par
    \Large\sffamily\mdseries Department\par}
    \vspace{2\baselineskip}
    {\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries TITLE\par}
    \vfill
    {\Large Master's Thesis\\ 30 \textsc{ects} points\par}
    \vfill
    {\large \textbf{Author}\par
    NAME\par
    EDUCATION\par
    \textbf{Supervisors}\par
    NAME AND TITLE\par
    \textbf{Submitted}\par
DATE\par}

\vspace{\drop}

    % adjust distance here to make the picture and the text overlap
%\includegraphics[width=.35\linewidth]{example-image-a}\par
{\color{gray!50}\fontsize{40pt}{56pt}\usefont{T1}{qzc}{m}{it} Christoffer\par}
\vspace{-.7\baselineskip}
    {\large\normalfont\bfseries NAME\par}
\end{titlepage}
}
\begin{document}
\titleMS
\end{document}
```