# How to add a zoombox effect to different images?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, zooming

According to [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25414/how-to-create-magnified-subfigures-and-corresponding-boxes-for-portions-of-a-lar) it is possible to create magnified subfigures and corresponding boxes for portions of a large image like this one:

[image]

I would like obtain the same effect but with different subfigures i.e. **not magnified from figure a**. It is possible? How?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If not from `a`, then from where to magnify?

Comment: Please provide an MWE! Your question could be reduced to two images (on of them bordered) with a line between the two subfigures. The rectangles can be done like http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30427 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559. As Harish pointed out, the link to the magnifying is quite useless here.

Comment: The subfigures are magnified a part (manually)... Image A is a map, subfigures B should be photos

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one possible approach using Caramdir's solution linked in the comments as a starting point in conjunction with the package [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe,subcaption,tikz}
\tikzset{boximg/.style={remember picture,red,thick,draw,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[boximg]
      \node[anchor=south west] (img) {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}};
      \begin{scope}[x=(img.south east),y=(img.north west)]
        \node[draw,minimum height=1.6cm,minimum width=1.00cm] (B1) at (0.2,0.60) {};
        \node[draw,minimum height=0.8cm,minimum width=0.50cm] (B2) at (0.7,0.25) {};
        \node[draw,minimum height=0.4cm,minimum width=0.25cm] (B3) at (0.9,0.10) {};
      \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}\\[0.5\baselineskip]
  \begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[boximg]
      \node (img1) {\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-10x16}};
      \draw (img1.south west) rectangle (img1.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}\hfill%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[boximg]
      \node (img2) {\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-10x16}};
      \draw (img2.south west) rectangle (img2.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}\hfill%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[boximg]
      \node (img3) {\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-10x16}};
      \draw (img3.south west) rectangle (img3.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,boximg]
    \draw (B1) -- (img1);
    \draw (B2) -- (img2);
    \draw (B3) -- (img3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{The National Gallery of Canada}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]