# Using \vspace togehter with \hspace to place a citation over an image

Tags: includegraphics, stacking-symbols, stackengine, vspace

I have an image I would like to don with a citation. However, placing the citation on top of the image has proven to be a bit of a challenge. Simply placing the citation after the image with

```
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{image.jpg}\cite{source[1]}
```

produces the following result:

[image: Citation after an image.]

As you can see, the citation appears outside of the image, which is not surprising. Using

```
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{image.jpg}\hspace{-1em}\cite{source}
```

moves the citation on top of the image horizontally:

[image: Picture citation with negative hspace.]

In the last image, it an be seen that the citation is still partly outside of the image, so I attempted the following:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{image.jpg}\vspace{-0.5em}\hspace{-1em}\cite{source}
```

However, this changes nothing:

[image: Image citation with vspace and hspace.]

Why is this, and how could I apply `\vspace` and `\hspace` simultaneously to a citation, in order to properly place it on top of an image? I also accept more elegant solutions.

Comment: You should probably consider adding that information via the caption for this image instead. That is generally the most accepted way. Also when posting here, please post a full minimal example instead of sniplets like this, then we have a better idea of what exactly you are doing, For image replacements you can use the images that come along with the mwe package.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260775/how-to-place-text-over-an-image

Comment: I would add a caption, if this was actually a presentation I was making for a scientific conference, but in this case it would just take up unnecessary space on the slide. I will add a MWE in just a second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usage of `\stackinset` places the citation with a 2pt gap at the bottom right of the image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,filecontents,stackengine}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@TECHREPORT{segl83,
 AUTHOR = "Segletes, Steven B.",
 TITLE   = "Drift Velocity Computations for Shaped-Charge Jets",
        NUMBER  = "ARBRL-MR-03306 (ADA 133 756)",
        INSTITUTION = "Army Ballistic Research Laboratory (US)",
        ADDRESS = "Aberdeen Proving Ground (MD)",
 YEAR = "1983",
 MONTH = sep    }
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\stackinset{r}{2pt}{b}{2pt}{\cite{segl83}}{\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image}}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Raise a bit a zero width box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}% <-- Don't forget
\raisebox{1ex}{\makebox[0pt][r]{\cite{uthor}\ }}

\caption{Image with citation}

\end{figure}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{uthor} A. Uthor, A paper.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]