# Is it possible to let text continue over an image?

Tags: graphics, text, gradient

I would like to achieve a result such as the one in the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kI7bX69BMKjOMyaFnwjoqBgdWJ9M-AK4/view

[image]

I thought of doing some kind of gradient to the image, but the text still (logically) does not go over the image. And I have a background already, so I could not just use it as a background with gradient...

Any tips?

Comment: No, I meant that I have a big block of text and part of the image can slide under the text. Like the tip of the knight in my OP picture. So overlapping, without being completely within the image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to place text over an image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260775/how-to-place-text-over-an-image) or [How to use background image in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167719/how-to-use-background-image-in-latex)

Comment: Not really, Tobi. I am trying to have a partial overlap of an image and text while keeping my current background.

Comment: Will the overlap you seek always be on the top/bottom of the image, or will it also be required from left/right side of the image?

Comment: Bottom for sure, top probably too. If it's possible, it would also be nice in the middle, but not sure whether that's possible too!

Answer (score 2):

This may (or may not) serve the purpose of overlapping images with text along either the top or bottom (not sides).  However, because it uses `opacity` and the page is typeset in order of occurrence, the appearance of overlapped top will slightly differ from overlapped bottom.  In particular, text overlapping the bottom of the image, because it is placed on top, will be fully dark.  Text overlapping the top, because it is under the image, will be a little washed out with opacity.

The macro I provide is

```
\overlap{<top overlap>}{<bottom overlap>}{<content>}
```

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum,tikz}
\newcommand\overlap[3]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\raisebox{-\dimexpr#2}{#3}}%
  \dp0=0pt\relax
  \ht0=\dimexpr\ht0-#1\relax
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[opacity=.4]{\copy0};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\centerline{%
  \overlap{0pt}{20pt}{\includegraphics[height=60pt]{example-image}}%
}

\lipsum[2]

\centerline{%
  \overlap{20pt}{0pt}{\includegraphics[height=60pt]{example-image}}%
}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `tikz` with option `remember picture, overlay`. Note that you have to put the picture at begin of current page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\begin{document}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
  \fill[red!30] (current page text area.north west) rectangle ++(\textwidth, -6cm);
}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So that means that if I only wanted the last paragraph to overlap with an image at the bottom, it would not be possible? Or could I do some other adjustments? I think I will experiment with this too once at home.

Comment: Yeah, I think it is a difficult thing.

Comment: Such a pity. I especially was looking for a bottom image blending.

Comment: But not impossible.  The origin will be at the tikzpicture location in the source (equivalent to \hbox{})  so if you know how how big the paragraph is, you can position an image using relative coordinates.

Comment: I will try today some things out, see if it works!