# Overpic a semitransparent rectangle on graphics

Tags: beamer, overpic

I know with `overpic` you can put text on top of an image, as explained in this [question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20792/how-to-superimpose-latex-on-a-picture).

I need to add text to the image but I need it placed on top of a white semitransparent rectangle so that it can be seen. The idea is explained in the following picture taken from the link above (think of the solid white rectangle as semitransparent, excuse my poor editing skills).

[image]

I tried overlaying text inside a transparent colored box as

```
\begin{overpic}[width=\linewidth]{image.png}
    \put (0, 2.3){ %
        \hspace{-0.1pt}\hspace{-5pt}%
        \pgfsetfillopacity{0.5}%
        \colorbox{white}{%
            \parbox{\linewidth}{\pgfsetfillopacity{1}\hspace{25pt}\color{black} image text  \hspace{10pt}} }}
\end{overpic}
```

But the white box surrounding the text surpasses the bonds of the image and I am left with parts of white rectangles on the background (my background is grey). Which is weird cuz both the image, and colorbox are set to `linewidth`, if I make the width of the colorbox smaller then it's off centered (using `\centering` doesn't do anything).
[image]

There has to be a way to place a semitransparent rectangle within the confinements of the image but I don't know how. Thank you for any help you might have!

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\hspace{-15pt}
\begin{minipage}{0.251\linewidth}
\vspace{10pt}
\begin{overpic}[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \put (0, 2.3){ %
        \hspace{-0.1pt}\hspace{-5pt}%
        \pgfsetfillopacity{0.5}%
        \colorbox{white}{%
            \parbox{\linewidth}{\pgfsetfillopacity{1}\hspace{25pt}\color{black} text \hspace{10pt}} }}

    \put (-1.95, 15.5){%
        \hspace{-0.1pt}\hspace{-2.2pt}%
        \pgfsetfillopacity{0.5}%
        \colorbox{white}{%
            \parbox{\linewidth}{\pgfsetfillopacity{1} \color{black}\hspace{1pt} image text } }}
\end{overpic}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`overpic` seems to use `tikz`, so advertizing `tikz` here may be in order. The question how to add something on top of a pic has [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/121799), which may be relevant if you want to see the grid. Otherwise just do

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\hspace{-15pt}
\begin{minipage}{0.251\linewidth}
\vspace{10pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) 
{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}};
\node[fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,anchor=south,text width=\linewidth-2pt,
inner xsep=1pt,inner ysep=3pt,outer sep=0pt,align=center,text opacity=1] at (image.south){text\\ more text};
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/121799
%     \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
%         \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
%         \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
%         \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
%     \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another way of making text more visible is to use the `contour` package.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{contour}
\contourlength{1pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\hspace{-15pt}
\begin{minipage}{0.251\linewidth}
\vspace{10pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) 
{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}};
\node[%fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,
anchor=south,text width=\linewidth-2pt,
inner xsep=1pt,inner ysep=3pt,outer sep=0pt,align=center,text opacity=1] at 
(image.south){\contour{white}{text}\\ \contour{white}{more text}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer works great

Comment: A good alternative would be the tikz-onimage package as explained here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30435/201329