# Specify some region and align text in that space

Tags: positioning, alignment, datatool

I want to use package datatool for putting different names in one specified space of one image. Here for everyone's convenience I've formed a tikzpicture instead of image. Please see this minimal code.

```
\begin{filecontents}{abcd.csv}
a, b, c
Niranjan, Tambe, Vikas
Sushant, Devalekar, Shankar
Pranav, Patwardhan, Sachin
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{tikz}
\DTLloaddb{abc}{abcd.csv}

\begin{document}
\DTLforeach{abc}{\firstname=a,\surname=b,\father=c}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-3,0) node[above]{\firstname{} \father{} \surname{} \\} -- (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}\\
}
\end{document}
```

If we look at the output, I've got the names above the line. Now I want to do further things, which I don't know how to do. I want every name at the center of that line. Please note that optional arguments of `node` like `[near end]` are not useful for me right now as I want to implement all of this on an .jpg image. For now let's assume that the tikz code presented is frozen and we can't change it. It is here just for the sake of convenience and to avoid uploading a file. I want something which will allow me to specify some portion of the document and apply regular LaTeX commands on it. Please suggest me how to make LaTeX apply some commands like `centering` or `center` environment "only" on the specified portion of the document.

Comment: So you have a picture as a »background« and in the foreground you would like to print some words on it? If so, the eso-pic package is your friend.

Comment: Yes, I know that package a bit, but let's say on the left corner of that image I have a 1 cm line (like in the question). I want to specify that much portion in the code and with `datatool` package, add many names on that line, but keeping in mind all the names should be centrally alligned. (I hope I am not confusing :P) Is eso-pic still helpful for this kind of specifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question. But you can set coordinates in a tikzpicture and use them later to place your text:

```
\begin{filecontents}{abcd.csv}
a, b, c
Niranjan, Tambe, Vikas
Sushant, Devalekar, Shankar
Pranav, Patwardhan, Sachin
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\DTLloaddb{abc}{abcd.csv}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\draw (-3,0)coordinate(a1)  -- (3,0)coordinate(b1);
\draw (-2,1)coordinate(a2)  -- (4,1)coordinate(b2);
\draw (-1,2)coordinate(a3)  -- (4,2)coordinate(b3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\DTLforeach{abc}{\firstname=a,\surname=b,\father=c}{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[above] at ($(a\number\value{DTLrowi})!0.5!(b\number\value{DTLrowi})$)
   {\firstname{} \father{} \surname{}};
 \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can place with tikz an (invisible) grid over the images and then use the coordinates like in my example to add the text. See e.g. [Simplest way to overlay a text + rectangle label an image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30427/simplest-way-to-overlay-a-text-rectangle-label-an-image) and [Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz).

Comment: Thanks Urlike for your effort, but sorry. This is not what I wanted. I am looking for a tool which enables me to specify some space over an image. I've mentioned that tikz commands do not seem to be helpful here. The tikz-code presented by me was an example code, to avoid image uploads. This is not a tikz question. Let me explain my question again. eg. If we use WYSIWYG image editing tools like 'inkscape', we can insert a text box wherever we want and align (l/c/r) the text inside it. With the help of co-ordinates can we achieve this in LaTeX? Placing alignment-friendly text-boxes anywhere.

Comment: Please use my tikz-code as an uneditable image and try to insert some positioning commands.

Comment: You can place with tikz an (invisible) grid over the images and then use the coordinates like in my answer to add the text. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30427/simplest-way-to-overlay-a-text-rectangle-label-an-image

Comment: Oh if that's the case, it is exactly what I'm searching for, but unfortunately I didn't understand those commands. The answers referred by you cleared the doubts. Thanks. +1 :)